# How to upload a lot of files at once using FileZilla (possibly using a file containing the list of files to publish)?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, publishing, filezilla

Is there a way, using FileZilla, to publish many files at once (currently I have to choose them one by one every time, because they can be in different directories and I can't publish the whole directory)?

The ideal solution I am looking for is to use a single .txt file where I can paste the list of paths I want to publish and then somehow tell FileZilla to use it and publish each file to the remote server.

FileZilla lets you export the list of the files you have published with `File -> Export` in XML format. I am looking for something like this but I need to do the opposite operation.

If someone has some insights on it, please share them with me. Thanks!

P.S.: currently, I also use NetBeans IDE and publish files with it by clicking with the right button of the mouse and selecting `Upload`. If there's a way to do the same with NetBeans, that would be great (I write PHP code).

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla does not allow any kind of automation.

See [How do I send a file with FileZilla from the command line?](https://superuser.com/q/239860/213663)

---

But you can use any other command-line FTP client.

For example [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) has [Uploading a list of files](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_file_list) example that exactly covers your task:

> You may use following batch file that calls WinSCP [script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting):
>
> ```
> @echo off
> set SESSION=ftp://user:password@example.com/
> set REMOTE_PATH=/home/user/
>
> echo open %SESSION% >> script.tmp
>
> rem Generate "put" command for each line in list file
> for /F %%i in (list.txt) do echo put "%%i" "%REMOTE_PATH%" >> script.tmp
>
> echo exit >> script.tmp
>
> winscp.com /script=script.tmp
> set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
>
> del script.tmp
>
> rem Propagating WinSCP exit code
> exit /b %RESULT%
> ```

Comment: Great! Although, this seems to be available only on Windows. Do you know if there's something like this for Unix-like OSs?

Comment: Writing such script in *nix shell should be even easier than in Windows batch file - If you need *nix solution, you should add relevant tags to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I found some useful infos about *nix here `https://superuser.com/questions/493021/ftp-upload-a-list-of-files-saved-in-a-txt-preserving-the-path-in-the-server-side/493641#493641` and here `http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/ftp/ftp_script_linux.htm`. Thanks!